# Netty's HttpContent Chunk cuts off json - Unexpected end-of-input in field name

Tags: java, json, jackson, netty

I am trying to make a Jackson parser that will use streaming API and convert JSON into object array. My JSON is very large so the parser takes chunk at a time received from the Netty's HttpContent object and tries to parse it. The problem is that the chunk usually gets cut off in the middle of a JSON object and parser throws an error: **Unexpected end-of-input in field name**

This is what I mean by a cut off JSON:

```
    {
        "region": 8,
        "requestType": "PRIORITY",
        "a
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

**ChannelRead** that sends chunks into parser:

```
 @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpContent httpContent) throws Exception {
        ByteBufInputStream in = new ByteBufInputStream(httpContent.content());
        jsonRead(in, tasks);
    }
```

**The parser:**

```
public static void jsonRead(InputStream is, List<Task> tasks) throws IOException {
        try (JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createParser(is)) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                    Task task = new Task();
                    while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                        String eventFieldName = parser.getCurrentName();
                        switch (eventFieldName) {
                            case "region" -> {
                                parser.nextToken();
                                task.setRegion(parser.getText());
                            }
                            case "requestType" -> {
                                parser.nextToken();
                                task.setRequestType(parser.getText());
                            }
                            case "atmId" -> {
                                parser.nextToken();
                                task.setAtmId(parser.getText());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    tasks.add(task);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```